# WordPress: Remove admin pages but still can access directly.

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a WordPress installation on my test server secure so that I can give a client access but they can't f*$K it up (which I just spent a few hours fixing) by installing themes and plugins etc...

So I looked around and found a solution which you add to the functions.php file:

```
function custom_remove_admin_menus (){

  if ( function_exists('remove_menu_page') ) { 
    remove_menu_page('themes.php');
    remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
  }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_remove_admin_menus');
```

This works in the respect as it removed the links in the admin panel sidebar, however if you go to those pages directly they still show up.

Is there a way to restrict these pages to a certain user like super_admin or something. I do not want to install another plugin or faff around with having to update it or edit the core so I hope there is a simple solution I can add to the functions file.

Comment: Technically yes it's doable, but honestly just find a good roles plugin and use that. To do it you have to create a new custom role, then edit the roles of the Admin role so it can no longer access those pages AND so it can't create new users and assign your new custom role. This just seems like a massive headache to me.

To my knowledge those features should only be available to admins anyway. Everyone shouldn't be an admin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create user account on admin dashboard and assign role as editor or author. Editor / Author does not have permissions to do anything with themes and plugins. When a user(Role : Author/ Editor) logs in admin dashboard, he/she won't see appearance and plugins in sidebar.

Hope this helps

Comment: ^^ this. Making users admins is a bad idea unless they're actually doing anything that requires it. If you're creating a site for a client then you have to educate them on what they should and shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use current screen id using get current screen function. check current user id and and redirect user. current screen function may not work in init of admin_init hook, so you can add it in enqueue scripts hook and redirect user using JS code.